# How to get fb posts of a mentioned page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I'm admin of a Facebook Page and i'm trying to get by API or FQL, contents posted on private streams wall mentioning my page.
If i try

`SELECT type,target_id, post_id, message, actor_id, tagged_ids FROM stream WHERE source_id=PAGEID`

i will get only: my posts(or page's) on the page wall, posts by a user on the pages wall, **but i can't see posts by a user on their own wall that tags the page.**
**Every user that visit my page can see them, so they should be accessible** by some API...but i can't understand how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to get this information by querying the `stream_tag` table, but in my tests I can't get it to return any data.

If the posts are visible on your page, you should be able to get at the posts mentioning you with this query:

```
SELECT type, target_id, post_id, message, actor_id, tagged_ids 
    FROM stream WHERE source_id =PAGEID AND actor_id !=PAGEID
```

Comment: the examples given on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/ returned empty data too

Comment: looks like stream_tag api work if you use users id as parameters and not with pages id

Comment: cpilko solution works with posts written on Page wall but there's no trace of posts with a tag to my page written in user's wall

Comment: Yes, this won't get all tagged posts, justs posts made by others on your page's timeline. To get posts on other's pages where you are tagged, you need to query stream_tag to get that. I can't get stream_tag queries to work on a user object either.

Comment: graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id,actor_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id=me() try this with permissions, should work

Comment: Got it. Needed `friends_photo_video_tags` to get this.

Comment: Do you guys know how to do that in the new version of graph API 2.5 ?